# How to pass a null value to a data driven unit test from a CSV file?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I have a unit test written in c# that uses a .CSV as a datasource:

```
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\TestData.csv", "TestData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("TxRP.Tests\\TestData.csv"), TestMethod()]
    public void CompareOrgsTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var vdd = new Mock<ViewDataDictionary>().Object;
        HtmlHelper helper = MVCMocks.CreateMockHelper(vdd);
        string orgOne = testContextInstance.DataRow["OrgOne"].ToString();
        string orgTwo = testContextInstance.DataRow["OrgTwo"].ToString();
        bool expected = Convert.ToBoolean(testContextInstance.DataRow["OrgCompareExpected"]); 

        // Act
        bool actual = HtmlHelpers.CompareOrg(helper, orgOne, orgTwo);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Did not return " + expected + ".  Org1=" + orgOne + ", Org2=" + orgTwo);
    }
```

Works fabulously, until I needed to add some null value testing.  I can't seem to figure out how to pass a NULL value as one of the data elements...has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the obvious - blank cell, typing in NULL, none of those worked.

Comment: What type of data are you dealing with? Integers, Strings, multiple types? When you say untill you needed a null value, what exactly happens, does the program just crash?  Does the documention on Mock speak of how to deal with null values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  You're reading in values from a CSV file.  There is no such thing as a 'null' value in a CSV file.  The next best thing I know to do would be to write some code to test 'null' if a 'magic string' is read from the CSV file.

```
string orgOne = testContextInstance.DataRow["OrgOne"].ToString();
if (orgOne=="null")
    orgOne = null;
```

Comment: Or simply convert empty strings to null?

Comment: I would not recommend converting empty strings to null in this context because you may want your code to treat empty strings and null strings differently.

Comment: I guess several data-driven tests and one null test is still better than a ton of separate tests.